# Changing single lines in methods in MS reference source code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

referring to
[WPF DocumentViewer.Print fails when printing to PDF but only from my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418761/wpf-documentviewer-print-fails-when-printing-to-pdf-but-only-from-my-application)

The suggestion was to change the line that calls `XpsDocumentWriter.WriteAsync` to use `XpsDocumentWriter.Write` instead.

I have the same problem but no idea how to realize this proposal.

So my question is how to change something in MS source code?

Is it like this:

```
public class MyDocumentViewer : DocumentViewer
{
    protected override void OnPrintCommand()
    {
        base.OnPrintCommand();
    }
}
```

??

Sorry for stupid question.

Thankful for any help.

Comment: *I lifted DocumentViewer's printing code and copied it it to my own source.* what did you not understand?

Comment: What do you mean, you lifted DocumentViewer's printing code and copied it it to your own source. Did you copied DocumentViewerBase in your project and changed the print method? Could you give an example?

Comment: I am the person who originally posted that question you linked to.  While it's true that I did get my document printing with that trick, I am sorry to say that in the long run the approach proved to be unwieldy and eventually I was force to abandon it.   I was stuck with some documents printing perfectly and others printing out as empty PDFs.  The only completely reliable workaround I found was to use a 3rd party print-to-PDF driver (e.g. "doPDF" but there are others)  I tried several of them and they would all print perfectly where the Microsoft one would not.

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks for that info! Even so I don't know how to change lines in MS source code. Do I have to copy thousands of lines of DocumentViewerBase.cs to my project?

Comment: I just don't know what it means to "lift" DocumentViewer's printing code...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override the method...!

```
public class MyDocumentViewer : DocumentViewer
{
    protected override void OnPrintCommand()
    {
        #if !DONOTREFPRINTINGASMMETA
            System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter docWriter;
            System.Printing.PrintDocumentImageableArea ia = null;
 
            // Only one printing job is allowed.
            if (_documentWriter != null)
            {
                return;
            }
 
            if (_document != null)
            {
                // Show print dialog.
                docWriter = System.Printing.PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref ia);
                if (docWriter != null && ia != null)
                {
                    // Register for WritingCompleted event.
                    _documentWriter = docWriter;
                    _documentWriter.WritingCompleted += new WritingCompletedEventHandler(HandlePrintCompleted);
                    _documentWriter.WritingCancelled += new WritingCancelledEventHandler(HandlePrintCancelled);
 
                    // Since _documentWriter value is used to determine CanExecute state, we must invalidate that state.
                    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
 
                    // Write to the PrintQueue
                    if( _document is FixedDocumentSequence )
                    {
                        docWriter.WriteAsync(_document as FixedDocumentSequence);
                    }
                    else if( _document is FixedDocument )
                    {
                        docWriter.Write(_document as FixedDocument);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        docWriter.Write(_document.DocumentPaginator);
                    }
                }
            }
#endif // DONOTREFPRINTINGASMMETA
    }
}
```

Comment: When trying this I get the errors that _document and _documentWriter and other does not exist. Do I have to generate new fields?